trying to install some android studio component, I've come across some problems
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\DELL USER\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\caches\transforms-4\f2cfbe96f4ea4bebc97720eee3299b1c-73531c2c-8806-4990-a8a1-a254d9939c15) to immutable location (C:\Users\DELL USER\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\caches\transforms-4\f2cfbe96f4ea4bebc97720eee3299b1c)
i tried downloading android studio setups but i have a problem, it keeps showing me [Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\DELL USER\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\caches\transforms-4\f2cfbe96f4ea4bebc97720eee3299b1c-73531c2c-8806-4990-a8a1-a254d9939c15) to immutable location (C:\Users\DELL USER\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\caches\transforms-4\f2cfbe96f4ea4bebc97720eee3299b1c)]
